# What does the Zstandard dual license mean?

Tags: gpl, bsd, multi-licensing

I am looking at the [Zstandard](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) library and it says that it is dual licensed, BSD and GPLv2. What does it mean? If I use libraries in a non open source program will the license be GPL or BSD?

In the source files I can see this text:

> you may select either version 2 of the GNU General Public License ("GPL") or BSD license ("BSD").

Does this mean that I can use the code and just apply the BSD license to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does this mean that I can use the code and just apply the BSD license to it?

Yes, this is means exactly this. This is somewhat redundant since the 3-clause BSD they use is already considered as "compatible" with the GPL.

As a user, you can elect to use either license, therefore you can pick the BSD license and ignore the GPL alright if you wish to do so.

Offering a choice of license is a somewhat common approach. And choice is good within reason, though it can be abused to absurd (or funny) levels, such as in this [8-way choice](https://github.com/dchest/pyblake2/blob/0fffd1d8b833c9a4db2748a04163253cfddfc4bf/COPYING):

> PYBLAKE2 IS OCTUPLE-LICENSED UNDER THE FOLLOWING LICENSES
> (choose one or several at your own discretion):
>
> - CC0 Universal 1.0 - http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0
> - Unlicense — http://unlicense.org/
> - WTFPL Version 2 - http://www.wtfpl.net/
> - Apache Public License 2.0 - https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
> - OpenSSL License - https://www.openssl.org/source/license.html
> - MIT License - https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
> - The BSD 3-Clause License - https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
> - ISC License - https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC